# Verification of function function in Isabelle

Tags: function, isabelle, proof

datatype mnat = mnat nat | MInfty

```
fun lookup :: "(nat×nat) ⇒ (nat×nat×mnat)list ⇒ mnat option"
  where "lookup (x,y) [] = None"|
        "lookup (x,y) ((a,b,c)#ps) = (if (a=x∧b=y) then Some c else lookup (x,y) ps)"
```

```
function update :: " (nat×nat×mnat)list ⇒nat⇒nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat ⇒  (nat×nat×mnat)list "
  where "update t x y i j =(if i≤x∧length t<(x*y)∧length A+1≥(Suc i)∧x≥1∧y≥1 then 
                                    if (j≤y) then
                                      if (A!(i-1)=B!(j-1))  then update ((i,j,mnat_plus (opt_mnat(lookup (i-1,j-1) t)) (mnat 1))#t) x y i (Suc j)
                                                   else update ((i,j,mnat_max (opt_mnat(lookup (i,j-1) t)) (opt_mnat(lookup (i-1,j) t)))#t) x y i (Suc j)
                                              else update t x y (Suc i) 1
                                         else t
                                  )"
  by pat_completeness auto
termination 
  apply (relation "measure(λ(t,x,y,i,j). (x*y+length A-length t-i))")
     apply auto
  done
declare update.simps[simp del]
```

```
lemma update_rec1:
"snd(snd(hd(update [] x y 1 1))) = (if (A!(i-1)=B!(j-1)) then mnat_plus (snd(snd(hd(update [] (x-1) (y-1) 1 1)))) (mnat 1)
                                          else mnat_max (snd(snd(hd(update [] (x-1) y 1 1)))) (snd(snd(hd(update [] x (y-1) 1 1)))))"
if "1≤x∧x≤length A" "1≤y∧y≤length B"
```

According to the definition of the update function, I want to verify the update_ rec1, but I don't have any ideas, or I don't know the update_rec1 to be verified?Can you give me some suggestions or ideas on whether the update_rec1 theorem is true?
Thank you.

Comment: How would you prove that on paper?

Comment: @MathiasFleury  At present, I haven't deduced this theorem on paper. I wrote it according to the definition and test of the update function. The update function acts as a memo, storing the length values of all the longest common subsequences less than the length of List A and List B. lemma update_rec1:
"snd(snd(hd(update [] x y 1 1))) = (if (A!(x-1)=B!(y-1)) then mnat_plus (snd(snd(hd(update [] (x-1) (y-1) 1 1)))) (mnat 1)
                                          else mnat_max (snd(snd(hd(update [] (x-1) y 1 1)))) (snd(snd(hd(update [] x (y-1) 1 1)))))"
if "1≤x∧x≤length A" "1≤y∧y≤length B"

Comment: The rule of thumb of theorem proving: if you don't know how to prove it on paper, you cannot prove it in any proof assistant.